# Bootstrap offstet only on md doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, offset

Hello im trying to add offset only on medium device and hide this offset on others devices. I I looked through some others similar questions but any of them could solved my problem.

Here's code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" style="background-color: red"> 111 </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" style="background-color: blue"> 222 </div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-1" style="background-color: black"> 333 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2" style="background-color: orange"> 444 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So the problem is that it add offset on every device not only on medium how it should be.

Screen on large: https://zapodaj.net/f4b34ebc771fb.png.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think offset needs to be "reset" on larger screens, otherwise it inherits the previous value.  Using `col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-0` seems to fix the issue.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" style="background-color: red"> 111 </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-0" style="background-color: blue"> 222 </div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-1" style="background-color: black"> 333 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2" style="background-color: orange"> 444 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your offset on medium devices use `col-md-offset-1` and not `col-sm-offset-1`.

You also need to reset the offset for large devices with `col-lg-offset-0`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" style="background-color: red">111</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-0" style="background-color: blue">222</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-1" style="background-color: black">333</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2" style="background-color: orange">444</div>
  </div>
</div>
```